# How to show data for the past 2 months only in laravel API?

Tags: php, laravel, api

i am getting data from API to show in blade

controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $response = Http::post('http://example.com/authenticate', [
        'Username' => 'ADMIN',
        'Password' => 'ADMIN',
        'Token' => 'FK98DL..',
    ]);
    $token = json_decode($response, true);
    $apiURL = 'http://example.com/api/SalesOrder/';
    $headers = [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => $token,
    ];
    $response2 = Http::withHeaders($headers)->get($apiURL);
    $data = $response2->json();
    return view('api.auth.orders.index', compact('data'));
}
```

blade view:

```
@foreach ($data as $item)
<tr>
<td>{{$item['DocDate']}}</td>
</tr>                                             
@endforeach
```

Output:

[image]

now my question is, how can i show the above data for the past 2 months of the current year (August and July of 2022)?

i tried to use Carbon in my previous question:
[how to display data in table for the past 3 months only in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73411946/how-to-display-data-in-table-for-the-past-3-months-only-in-laravel)

but it ignore the year, is there any other approach for this problem?

Comment: Do You Create/maintain your own api? if so you it would be best to filter by passing the dates you want your data between if not filtering the data after the api response in controller will be best option for you as you don't have to load all the data in view. Take this https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-filter for example. Create collection of your response and filter based on that. If you really want to do it on blade then check if the $item['DocDate'] is between your filterable date i.e. between August and July of 2022 if it is then print else don't print the data

Answer (score 0):

you either change the code in API to return only last 2 months or add some change in your blade to check the months

```
@foreach ($data as $item)
@if(date('m') == date('m', strtotime($item['DocDate'])) || date('m')-1 == date('m', strtotime($item['DocDate'])))
<tr>
<td>{{$item['DocDate']}}</td>
</tr>
@endif                                             
@endforeach
```